# Why do I have error when trying to do git push

Tags: angular, typescript, git

I run the following line git

```
git push origin <the-name-of-my-branch>
```

and I got the following warning

> no-use-before-declare is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use
> the built-in compiler checks instead. typeof-compare is deprecated.
> Starting from TypeScript 2.2 the compiler includes this check which
> makes this rule redundant. no-unused-variable is deprecated. Since
> TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.

and after this a lot of errors

output of running

```
ls .git/hooks
```

```
applypatch-msg                  post-checkout                   post-update.sample              pre-merge-commit.sample         pre-receive.sample
applypatch-msg.sample           post-commit                     pre-applypatch                  pre-push                        prepare-commit-msg
commit-msg                      post-merge                      pre-applypatch.sample           pre-push.sample                 prepare-commit-msg.sample
commit-msg.sample               post-receive                    pre-auto-gc                     pre-rebase                      push-to-checkout
fsmonitor-watchman.sample       post-rewrite                    pre-commit                      pre-rebase.sample               update
post-applypatch                 post-update                     pre-commit.sample               pre-receive                     update.sample
```

Comment: This isn't a git error. Do you have any hooks enabled in your repo?

Comment: no I do not have

Comment: @Mureinik I have read that you need to modify the tsconfig.json file and the tslint.json but it did not work for me

Comment: Do these errors show up in your IDE like VSCode?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls .git/hooks`, and `git config core.hooksPath` to your question ?

Comment: @LeGEC I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you have several hooks installed.

The one that triggers on `git push` is `pre-push`.

If you don't remember/don't know how it was installed and what it does, you can inspect its content by opening `.git/hooks/pre-push` in an editor.

---

From the looks of it : it tries at least to run the typescript compiler on your project.

The initial message you mention is just a warning message, and shouldn't be the cause of your failed job. You should inspect the errors mentioned after that to have a pointer to what is actually refused by the compiler.

As said in the comments by @AlexeyLarionov : you should see the same errors from your ide, or by invoking `tsc` from the command line on your project.